# How to Send a Object name as argument to function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want write a program that :
In `textbox` type a `picturebox` name and in other textbox type location number,then press `button` to move that `picturebox` that name is equal `textbox1` to that location.
my question is how  I can send a `object(picturebox)` to a `Function`?

Comment: Objects don't have names. Please be more specific.

Comment: You probably want a dictionary.

Comment: you mean the name of the image inside the pictureBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to move a picture box by entering its name into a textbox? Then this is a possibility:

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string pBoxName = textbox1.Text;
    // I don't quite understand what you mean by 'location number'
    int newPos = int.Parse(textbox2.Text);
    // boxList is a List<PictureBox>
    PictureBox pBox = boxList.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(pBoxName)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(pBox != null)
    {
        MoveTheBox(pBox, newPos);
    }
}

private void MoveTheBox(PictureBox box, int newPos)
{
    // move the box
}
```

Comment: thank you,a lot.but how must define boxlist.because i have error about that.thank very much **germi**

Comment: boxList is just a `List<PictureBox>`. Each time you create a new `PictureBox` just put it in the list: `boxList.Add(theNewPictureBox);` The easiest way is to declare the list as a class field (i. e. outside of all methods but inside your class).